# Proof that every $\kappa$-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to the vector space $(F^B)_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm reading **Advanced Linear Algebra** by Steven Roman and in chapter two there is a theorem which is left for the reader to prove:

> **Theorem 2.7**: If $n$ is a natural number, then any $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ is isomorphic to $F^n$. If $\kappa$ is any cardinal number, and if $B$ is a set of cardinality $\kappa$, then any $\kappa$-dimensional vector space over $F$ is isomorphic to the vector space $(F^B)_0$ of all functions from $B$ to $F$ with finite support.

The first part is clear to me, but I can't understand the second one, specially the requirement for the functions to have finite support. Could anyone give me a proof of this second part of the theorem? Thanks.

Comment: The vector space is spanned by the functions that take value $1$ at a single element of $B$ and are $0$ elsewhere. They also form a basis. You need finite support for that to work. Otherwise, you “jump” cardinalities. For example, the set of *all* functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space, but its dimension iis uncountable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I can understand why these functions form a basis for $(F^B)_0$, but I still didn't understand what is  to "jump" cardinalities. Sorry if I'm lacking understanding, but I'm still trying to comprehend the role of finite support in the context of linear algebra.

Comment: The role of the finite support is to control the dimension. If you do not restrict yourself to finite support, then these functions do not exhaust the space, and in fact the dimenision will not in general be just $\kappa$. The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, for example, is $\mathfrak{c}$, the cardinality of the continuum, and the existence of a basis depends on the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally been able to understand the isomorphism, and so I'll be posting an answer to my own question for anyone interested.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for $V$ of cardinality $\kappa$. Let $B$ be a set of same cardinality as $\mathcal{B}$. Then there exists a one-to-one correspondence between these two sets.

We now prove that $(F^B)_0$ is indeed a vector space. It is easy to see that the set is closed under addition and multiplication by $\lambda \in F$. The set of functions $\{ f_b \} \subseteq (F^B)_0$, defined for any $c \in B$ as
\begin{equation}
f_b(c) = 
\begin{cases} 
      1 & c = b \\
      0 & c \neq b
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is linearly independent, since evaluating the zero expression at any $b_j$ gives:
\begin{equation}
0 = \sum_i a_i f_{b_i} (b_j) = a_j \; .
\end{equation}
We can also see that $\{ f_i \}$ spans $(F^B)_0$, since any function with finite support from $B$ to $F$ is a finite linear combination of elements of $\{ f_i \}$.

Let $\tau \in \mathcal{L}((F^B)_0, V)$ be a linear transformation defined for any $f \in (F^B)_0$ as
\begin{equation}
\tau (f) = \sum_i f(h(c_i)) c_i = \sum_i f(b_i) c_i \; ,
\end{equation}
where $b_i \in B$ and $c_i \in \mathcal{B}$. We use $h: \mathcal{B} \to B$ as a bijection which converts an element from $\mathcal{B}$ to an equivalent from $B$. Such bijection exists given the equality of the cardinalities of both sets.

We now prove that $\tau$ is an isomorphism. It is an homomorphism:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tau (rf + sg) = \sum_i (rf + sg)(b_i) c_i = \sum_i (rf(b_i) + sg(b_i)) c_i \\
= r \sum_i f(b_i) c_i + s \sum_i g(b_i) c_i = r \tau (f) + s \tau (g) \; .
\end{split}
\end{equation}
It is also injective, since $\tau (f) = 0$ implies
\begin{equation}
 0 = \sum_i f(b_i) c_i \; ,
\end{equation}
and the linear independence of $\{ c_i \}$ implies that $f(b_i) = 0$ for all $b_i$ and so $f = 0$. Hence, $\operatorname{ker} (\tau) = \{ 0\}$.

Finally, it is surjective, since the output of all $f \in (F^B)_0$ contain all possible mappings with finite support to all possible values of $F$, therefore its functions produce all possible scalars in a linear combination in $V$. Hence, $\operatorname{im} (\tau) = V$.

We can then conclude that $V \approx (F^B)_0$.

Also, a shorter proof lies in the fact that each $\{ f_b \}$ in the basis of $(F^B)_0$ is defined for one $b \in B$, hence the dimension of $(F^B)_0$ is also $\kappa$. From there we have that two vector spaces with same dimension over a same field are isomorphic, as there is a bijection between their bases, which can be extended linearly.